# Is it allowed to place a capital letter after adverb?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, adverbs, capitalization

In sentences like:

```
Also, it provides ...

Also, It provides ...
```

is it allowed to place `It`(Capital `I`) instead of `it` after adverb `Also`?

Comment: Note: If you're asking because you saw someone saying "Also, It provides...", one reason that might happen is if they started out just saying "It provides..." and then decided to add an "Also" to make it flow better, but forgot to uncapitalize "It". However, this is just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

"Also" here is a conjunction, not an adverb. But in any case, the answer is "no". You use a capital to begin the first word of a sentence; proper nouns, i.e. names of people or things, like "Sally" or "the Eiffel Tower"; and the first person pronoun "I". Many writers capitalize pronouns that refer to God, like, "When God created the world, He made humans in His own image."

Writers sometimes capitalize all the letters in a word for emphasis, or if quoting someone, to indicate that the speaker said them more loudly or emphatically. Like, "No, don't go that way. STOP!"

Besides that, all the letters in a sentence should be small letters.